# Object Oriented in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have just made a [small online CAD demo](http://francisco.io/demo/cad/) for fun and learning. It is working perfectly for my intentions, but now I want to improve the code and I'm not sure of how to convert the current function-oriented code to Object Oriented. This is a small part of the code I have so far:

```
// DATA
var lines = [[]];
var circles = [{}];
var rectangles = [{}];

// Drawing functions
function drawLine(from, to){}
function drawCircle(center, radius){}
function drawRectangle(from, size){}

// Adding elements to the render chain
function addLine(e){}
function addCircle(e){}
function addRectangle(e){}
```

To get it Object Oriented, I can see two different ways. The first one is to group them by *domain*. This way there are many functions that can be reused within each of the classes:

```
var lines = [[]];
...

var draw = function(){
  var all() = function(){}
  var lines() = function(){}
  var circles() = function(){}
  var rectangles() = function(){}
  }

var add = function(){ ... }
...
```

The other one is to group them by *type*. This is the way I've read before about OO, since it's a representation of real world models and it's much more intuitive. The best part is that you have all the parts for the `rectangle` in the same small piece of code:

```
var rectangle = function(){
  var x, y, width, height;
  var draw = function(){}
  var add = function(){}
  }
...
```

**Which one follows closer the best OO patterns?**

Comment: Shapes are things. Verbs are what those things do. Objects should be things that have verbs, not the other way around.

Comment: What's the motive to make it object-oriented? What does that give you over what you have working now?

Comment: Javascript is not an object oriented language

Comment: maybe the following answer can help:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that's the answer I wanted, thank you. However, doesn't that go against MVC also? I mean, I could call it `painter.drawLines` instead of `draw.lines`, reversing the logic of it.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud to put code together in a manner that is easier to understand by others and the future me. It also allows me to organize it for whenever it grows, so it doesn't become an entangled mess.

Answer (score 0):

Caution, here, your methods are private:

```
var draw = function(){};
var add = function(){};
```

To make them public:

```
this.draw = function(){};
this.add = function(){};
```

Note: to respect strict pattern, ; is needed after a var set.

Else you can edit the prototype (better):

```
function Rectangle() {
  var x, y, width, height;
}
Rectangle.prototype.draw = function ();
```

Comment: Oops, I did the setting variables from memory and apparently wrong, thank you for the tip